Getting error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') at handleSubmit. Request is timing out, MERN app
I have a registration page that is supposed to post user input from a form:
// Registration.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Registration = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      // Validation logic (you can use a library like Yup for form validation)
      if (!email || !password) {
        setError('Email and password are required.');
        return;
      }
      console.log("Test");
      // Registration API call
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register', { email, password });
      console.log(response);
      setSuccessMessage(response.data.message);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.response.data.message);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <h2>Registration</h2>
          {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
          {successMessage && <div className="alert alert-success">{successMessage}</div>}
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} required />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
              <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} required />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Registration;


When I submit the form nothing happens, I go to the network tab to see whats going on and after a while of pending the request header eventually says 408 Request time out. Thats when these 3 show up in the console:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register net::ERR_FAILED 408 (Request Timeout)

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at handleSubmit (main.18ffb0dca439882a5d90.hot-update.js:50:31)

I'm not too sure its the first error because I set up proxy middleware for the cross origin access and the proxy request headers seem to be completing just fine every time:
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5000',
      changeOrigin: true, // Needed for virtual hosted sites
      ws: true, // Proxy websockets
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': '' // remove base path
      }
    })
  );
};

// server.js

const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db.js');
var cors = require('cors');
const proxyMiddleware = require('./middleware/Proxy.js');


const app = express();

// Connect to MongoDB
connectDB();

// Middleware
app.use(express.json()); // Parse JSON bodies
proxyMiddleware(app);

// Define CORS options
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true, // Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header
  optionSuccessStatus: 200
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Routes
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));

// Define port
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, welcome to the API server!');
});

// Start server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

module.exports=app;

Proxy response header:
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
x-powered-by: Express
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
access-control-allow-headers: content-type
content-length: 0
date: Wed, 17 Apr 2024 14:20:11 GMT
connection: close

I belive the problem lies in the last error, in an attempt to fix it I consol.log() the problem areas as shown by the registration.jsx page. The console log for test runs fine but the console log after this statement doesnt even run
const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register', { email, password });

Is there something wrong with the statement? I'll include anything I think you might need bellow, thanks in advance.
//auth.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/user.js');
const  registerValidation  = require('../middleware/validation.js');
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');
//Register Route
router.post('/register', registerValidation, async (req, res) => {
  // Validate request body
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // Check if user already exists
    let user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User already exists' });
    }

    // Create new user
    user = new User({
      email,
      password
    });

    // Hash password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    // Save user to database
    await user.save();

    // Generate JWT token
    const payload = {
      user: {
        id: user.id
      }
    };

    jwt.sign(
      payload,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: '1d' },
      (err, token) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json({ token });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

//Email Verification Route
router.get('/verify/:token', async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.params.token;
  
    try {
      // Verify token
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  
      // Update user's verified status
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(decoded.user.id, { verified: true });
  
      res.json({ msg: 'Email verified successfully' });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });

// Login Route
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
  
    try {
      // Check if user exists
      let user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid Credentials' });
      }
  
      // Check if password matches
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (!isMatch) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid Credentials' });
      }
  
      // Check if user is verified
      if (!user.verified) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Please verify your email' });
      }
  
      // Generate JWT token
      const payload = {
        user: {
          id: user.id
        }
      };
  
      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: '1d' },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.json({ token });
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });

// Forgot password route
router.post('/forgot-password', async (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;
  
    try {
      // Check if user exists
      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User not found' });
      }
  
      // Generate verification code
      const verificationCode = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
  
      // Implement logic to send verification code to user's email using SendGrid
  
      res.json({ msg: 'Verification code sent to your email' });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });
  
// Verify Code route
router.post('/verify-code', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, verificationCode } = req.body;
  
    try {
      // Check if user exists
      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User not found' });
      }
  
      // Check if verification code matches
      if (user.verificationCode !== verificationCode) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid verification code' });
      }
  
      // If verification code matches, update user's verified status
      user.verified = true;
      // Clear verification code after successful verification
      user.verificationCode = null;
      await user.save();
  
      res.json({ msg: 'Verification code verified' });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });
  
  //Rest Password route
  router.post('/reset-password', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, newPassword } = req.body;
  
    try {
      // Check if user exists
      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User not found' });
      }
  
      // Hash new password
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt);
  
      // Save new password to database
      await user.save();
  
      res.json({ msg: 'Password reset successful' });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });
  
  

module.exports = router;


{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Percy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^8.1.3",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^3.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.3.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.13",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "sendgrid": "^5.2.3"
  }
}

{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}


